# Mapping related attributes in a many to many relationship to their own 'virtual' columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have two many to many related tables and want to find out how to map specific values of the related table as attributes of the subject table.

Here's what I have using column_property and an association table:

```
class Assoc_Table(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'assoc_table'
  __table_args__ =  {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

  a_id = Column(Unicode(255), ForeignKey('a.id'), primary_key=True)
  b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'), primary_key=True)


class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'a'
  __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

  id   = Column(Unicode(255), primary_key=True)
  bees = relationship("B", secondary="assoc_table", back_populates="as")


class B(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'b'
  __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

  id       = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  as       = relationship("A", secondary="assoc_table", back_populates="bees")
  name     = Column(Unicode(255))
  category = Column(Integer)
```

One of the consumers of this data requires that table A should provide several columns (column_property/hybrid_property/plain_descriptor/something else?) containing the name attribute of several distinct items from the associated A.bees collection.  Something like this:

```
class A(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'a'
  __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset': 'utf8'}

  id   = Column(Unicode(255), primary_key=True)
  bees = relationship("B", secondary="assoc_table", back_populates="as")
  x    = column_property(select([B.name]).where(and_(Assoc_Table.a_id==id, Assoc_Table.b_id==B.id, B.category==1)).limit(1), deferred=True)
  y    = column_property(select([B.name]).where(and_(Assoc_Table.a_id==id, Assoc_Table.b_id==B.id, B.category==1)).limit(2), deferred=True)
  z    = column_property(select([B.name]).where(and_(Assoc_Table.a_id==id, Assoc_Table.b_id==B.id, B.category==2)).limit(1), deferred=True)
```

(Apologies if the syntax is a bit wonky, but this is close to what is implemented ATM).

Mapped attributes A.x & A.y are intended to hold the name attribute of the first & second related B table records (or None if there isn't a 1st/2nd related record) matched on B.category, similarly A.z should hold the name attribute of the first related B table record.  A.x & A.z do roughly what they should, but I don't know how to map A.y to the name attribute of the second related B record.

Is this even a useful way of attempting to model this?  I already have the A.bees relationship defined - can I utilize this to populate the A.x, A.y & A.z columns instead?

I don't feel like I'm expressing this very clearly, please feel free to ask for clarification if this isn't making sense...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it really wasn't that hard (or even really an sqlalchemy problem!).  The approach in the question was completely valid, just needed the SQL to select the second record into the 'y' column_property.  For MySQL (the target DB for this problem), the following syntax achieved the goal:

```
  x    = column_property(select([B.name]).where(and_(Assoc_Table.a_id==id, Assoc_Table.b_id==B.id, B.category==1)).limit(1), deferred=True)
  y    = column_property(select([B.name]).where(and_(Assoc_Table.a_id==id, Assoc_Table.b_id==B.id, B.category==1)).offset(1).limit(1), deferred=True)
  z    = column_property(select([B.name]).where(and_(Assoc_Table.a_id==id, Assoc_Table.b_id==B.id, B.category==2)).limit(1), deferred=True)
```